# Object Creation Differences in python

Tags: python

what is the difference between

```
object = Class()

object = Class
```

As both the above worked for me without giving any error in python 2

Comment: the first one creates an instance of the class; the second line is just a new name for the class... and it is a bad idea to overwrite [`object`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#object).

Comment: You should try to read some documentation/tutorials/guides/books/articles/b̶i̶b̶l̶e̶ before start to ask such as questions.

Comment: See what happens when you type `print(object)` after each of the statement. Also, if you feel adventurous, take a look at the [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) module and inspect both `object`s. (BTW, the second statement does _not_ create an object.)

Comment: If possible, you should switch to Python 3.7+ - https://pythonclock.org/

Answer (score 0):

Classes are first-class objects (no pun intended) in Python. The *name* `Class` refers to a value whose type is `type`; when a `type` value is called, it returns an instance of that type.

```
>>> class Class:
...   pass
...
>>> type(Class)
<class 'type'>
```

In your first example, the name `object` is assigned a value of type `Class`.

```
>>> object = Class(); object.__class__ is Class
True
```

In your second example, the name `object` is assigned the type `Class` itself.

```
>>> object = Class; object is Class
True
```